# SoapUI Custom Properties for Rest Service

Tags: java, rest, soapui, restful-url

I downloaded `SoapUI` from this [link](https://www.soapui.org/downloads/soapui.html) and created a new Rest project from URI under the file menu. Here is a picture:

[image]

Note in the link - I attempted to reference a custom project property called "fqdn." I expected that when I update the property value - it would update the project uri as specified. Here is the example:

[image]

Unfortunately, this did not work. The documentation mentions to use hashtags with the project name - I tried all permutations with no luck.

My intention is to have an easy way to update the link without changing the other project properties and method parameters.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can create properties at several levels.

You can create a Properties teststep, and create your property inside that.
From the top of my head, I believe you refer to it using the teststep name, followed by the parameter name

```
${Properties#fqdn}
```

This is one of the few instances, where you type the *name* of the teststep. So if you name it something different, you will need to adjust accordingly.

You can also place the property at the testcase, testsuite or project level, by selecting either one of testcase, testsuite or project, and then selecting the "Custom Properties", and create your parameter.
Then it can be referred to using

```
${#TestCase#fqdn}
${#TestSuite#fqdn}
${#Project#fqdn}
```

Finally you may use a global property. This can be useful, if you have one property you want to use across several different SoapUI projects, but be careful. Global properties are not saved with your project files.
You go into SoapUI properties, and find the pane for global properties. If you create it there, you just refer it using

```
${fqdn}
```